# PayPal IPN Listener in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, webforms, paypal-ipn

I'm seeing two different and contradictory statements in PayPal's API documentation.

When we send the parameters BACK to PayPal we add the "&cmd=_notify-validate" parameter. My question is, do we add it to the start of the query parameter list, or the end of it?

[Here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNImplementation/), we add it to the start of the parameter list, whereas [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/ht_ipn/#do-it), we add it to the end.

Which is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter. Both will work. It is much more forgiving than the docs imply.

This is based on personal experience. Feel free to test it yourself to verify.